# Remove trailing .0 from values in Python

Tags: python, sql, regex, pandas

When loading in an excel file, Pandas is ingesting a value (1735582) into a float value of (1735582.0). Subsequently, when importing the file to SQL, the value is ingested as a truncated scientific notation value (1.73558e+06), thereby rendering the value useless.

My first thought was to trim any trailing '.0' from all values, and then see if the import goes smoothly to retain the native values.

I have attempted to use the dataframe.replace to identify values across the entire dataframe that have a trailing '.0', but have no come up with the right solution:

`df_update = df.replace(to_replace ='\.\[0]$', value = '', regex = True)`

I need a way to 1) ingest the values without the trailing '.0', 2) remove the trailing '.0', or 3) prevent to_sql from outputting the values as truncated scientific notation.

Comment: I think you mean you get floats when loading data. Just tell pandas the column is of `int` (or `object`) type before doing it.

Comment: This will be applied to a batch of files with unknown fields/data types.

Comment: @Brian Francke: if you cannot set the parameter during loading, you can do it after, for ex. `df['A'].astype(int)`.

Comment: Pandas has a [set percision](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) option

Answer (score 0):

Just use `df.apply` and then use lambda with `"{:.2f}".format(x)` to limit it to 2 digits after the 0

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the whole column as int or str you can do:

```
df['column'].astype('str')
df['column'].astype('int32')
```